# Numpy integer does not convert to rgb

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, python-ggplot

I want to draw a very simple bar plot `identity` with Python ggplot library. I have a couple of categorical variables on the x-axis and a variable on y-axis and would like to fill barplots with the y-axis value:

```
import pandas as pd
from ggplot import *
import numpy as np

a= pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5) ,  index = np.arange(5))
a['second_column'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
a.columns = ['first_column', 'second_column']
ggplot(aes(x = 'second_column', y = 'first_column'), data = a) + \
geom_bar(aes(fill = 'first_column'), stat='identity')
```

What I get is:

```
<repr(<ggplot.ggplot.ggplot at 0x7f2d70cc12d0>) failed: ValueError: Cannot convert argument type <type 'numpy.int64'> to rgba array>
```

While if I remove the `fill` from aesthetics:

```
a= pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5) ,  index = np.arange(5))
a['second_column'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
a.columns = ['first_column', 'second_column']

ggplot(aes(x = 'second_column', y = 'first_column'), data = a) + \
geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

With no errors and a nice output:

[image]

Comment: The error message states that's the `dtype` is `np.int64`. Try `np.arange(5, dtype='float')

Comment: is it considered a bug for ggplot to report in issues on github?

Comment: @Arman Yes please. Can you also show the stacktrace (`g = ggplot(...) + ...` and then call `g.draw()`).

Comment: @Arman what happens if you do: `a = a.astype(np.int8)` or `astype(np.uint8)` before plotting?